# Getting "Error in as.vector(x.mode): cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'"

Tags: r

I keep getting the following error.

```
Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
```

I want to plot f2(x) versus x using the matplot option in RStudio. Is there something I'm missing?

```
f2<-function(x){
  if(x>=0){
    return(sqrt(x))
  }else{
    return(sqrt(-x))
  }
}

x<- seq(from= -5, to= 5, by= 0.001)

require(graphics)
matplot(f2, x, type = "1", xlab = expression(alpha), ylab = expression(sqrt(abs(alpha))))
```

Comment: You didn't apply `f2` on `x`.  Also, 'x' is a vector, so you may use `ifelse` instead of `if/else`

Answer (score 1):

The function `f2` was not applied on 'x'.  Having said that, `if/else` would not be efficient here as it is not vectorized and we may need to loop if we need to apply.  Instead another function with `ifelse` or within in the function create a logical index and replace the original vector based on the index

```
f1 <- function(v) {
  i1 <- v >= 0
  v[i1] <- sqrt(v[i1])
  v[!i1] <- sqrt(-v[!i1])
   v
 }
matplot(f1(x), type = "l", xlab = expression(alpha),
              ylab = expression(sqrt(abs(alpha))))
```

[image]